# Pandas convert txt/TXT to Excel, but one row is split to two rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I am using pandas to convert tab delimited txt to excel. Most of cases work well. But today I found an issue one row was split to two rows, I don't know reason.

I checked that row  and other rows which have similar patterns, but other rows don't split. I am confused.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.formats.excel
mypath = "Path"
#print(mypath)
from os import listdir
from os.path import join
#print (listdir(mypath))
textfiles = [ join(mypath,f) for f in listdir(mypath) if '.txt' in f.lower()]
#textfiles2= [join(mypath,f) for f in listdir(mypath) if '.txt' in f]
#print(textfiles2)
#textfiles.extend(textfiles2)
print(textfiles)

for textfile in textfiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(textfile,sep='|', dtype=str)
    #df.dtypes
    #df.ROW = df.ROW.astype(str)
    print(df.iloc[1])
    print(df.iloc[2])
    filename=textfile.split('.')[0]
    # Create a Pandas Excel writer  
    # object using XlsxWriter as the engine.  
    writer_object = pd.ExcelWriter(filename+'.xlsx', 
                                engine ='xlsxwriter') 
    # Write a dataframe to the worksheet.  
    # we turn off the default header 
    # and skip one row because we want 
    # to insert a user defined header there. 

    df.to_excel(writer_object, 'Sheet1', index=False) 
    # Create xlsxwriter workbook object . 
    workbook_object = writer_object.book 
    # Create xlsxwriter worksheet object 
    worksheet_object = writer_object.sheets['Sheet1'] 

    # Create a new Format object to formats cells  
    # in worksheets using add_format() method . 

    # here we create a format object for header. 
    header_format_object = workbook_object.add_format({ 
                                'bold': False, 
                                'border': 0}) 
    # Write the column headers with the defined format. 
    for col_number, value in enumerate(df.columns.values): 
        worksheet_object.write(0, col_number , value,  
                              header_format_object) 

    # Close the Pandas Excel writer  
    # object and output the Excel file.  
    writer_object.save()
```

No error message.
Source TXT:

```
Row|Month|CompanyName|Location|PRODUCT|Region|MEMBERID|CNN|CLIENTMEMBERID|MEMBERLASTNAME|MEMBERFIRSTNAME|DOB|GENDER|MEMBERADDRESS1|MEMBERADDRESS2|MEMBERCITY|MEMBERSTATE|MEMBERZIP|MEMBERPHONE

2574|201907|Apple|Palo Alto|OOO|California|7156||62980|Tim|Cook|06/01/2019|Male|4433 Mountain view||Sunnyvale|CA|95500|(999) 999-9999

2575|201907|Apple|Palo Alto|OOO|California|7158||63069|Tim|Cook|06/01/2019|Male|322 Sand AVENUE|1ST FL|Sunnyvale|CA|95500|(999) 999-9999

2576|201907|Apple|Palo Alto|OOO|California|7159||63128|Tim|Cook|06/01/2019|Male|187 Mountain view||Sunnyvale|CA|95500|(999) 999-9999

2577|201907|Apple|Palo Alto|OOO|California|7161||63145|Tim|Cook|06/01/2019|Male|145-40 21 AVE|PVT|Sunnyvale|CA|95500|(999) 999-9999

2578|201907|Apple|Palo Alto|OOO|California|7162||63222|Tim|Cook|06/01/2019|Male|2555 SAND AVENUE
||Sunnyvale|CA|95500|(999) 999-9999

2579|201907|Apple|Palo Alto|OOO|California|7163||63230|Tim|Cook|06/01/2019|Male|235 SAnd COURT||Sunnyvale|CA|95500|(999) 999-9999

2580|201907|Apple|Palo Alto|OOO|California|7164||63381|Tim|Cook|06/01/2019|Male|223 78TH STREET|3E|Sunnyvale|CA|95500|(999) 999-9999

2581|201907|Apple|Palo Alto|OOO|California|7165||63399|Tim|Cook|06/01/2019|Male|8739 26TH AVENUE|1|Sunnyvale|CA|95500|(999) 999-9999
```

[image: Source]

Result:
Row 2578 is split after 'AVENUE' below, Please run script and open excel then you will know.
[image: Split Row 2578]

Comment: Can you please check any character like new line, single quote, or double quotes be there in the file? Or you can share the sample data of these few records which causing you problem so I can try it and let you know the cause.

Comment: @Himmat Thanks. I pasted data, I don't know how to attach file.I didn't see any new line symbol. No quote for sure.

Comment: In the data in your example the line with the issue contains the following `"... SAND AVENUE\r\n||Sunnyvale|CA|..."`., i.e., the data is split onto 2 lines and hence it appears as 2 lines in the output.

Comment: @jmcnamara Thanks a lot.How did you identify the \r\n? why it works if I manually use excel 'Txt to column' to convert?Can I use python code to over this kind of corner case?